# Babel loader unable to handle Imports - give syntaxError: unexpected ID / token

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, babeljs, babel-loader

I have spent two days trying all the other stack overflow questions with simular problems but none were able to help. My babel loader looks correct in terms of i include both the presets and plugins, and its inside the module.

Problem:
So my app loads but my imports fail to work giving me errors such as Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token, or unexpected Identifier in the sources tab in crhome dev tools. If I delete the first import it will complain about the second import and so on.

Picture examples of the errors:

- [Picture of Import error message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfEC8.png)
- [Picture of Import error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68R7D.png)

Below are the configuration files I have, I beleve there must be an issue with my webpack thats making babel not work correctly.

imports from one file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router";
import { LOAD_YMMTT_DATA } from "./../reducers/constants";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { fetchYmmttData, getVisibleYmmttData } from "../reducers/ymmtt";
```

Webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: "./js/main.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader', 
          options: {
            presets: ['react', "env", "stage-2"],
            plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties' ]
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          // options: {
          //    name: '[sha512].[ext]'
          // }
        }, 
        {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          options: {
            bypassOnDebug: true,
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            interlaced:false
          }
        }]
      }
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    filename: "main.min.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-mobx-todos",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "dev-server": "json-server -p 8080 --watch db.json"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "mobx": "^2.7.0",
    "mobx-react": "^3.5.9",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
    "oracledb": "^2.0.15",
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.32.2",
    "sequelize-oracle": "^3.3.2-0.0",
    "treemap": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.10.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "1.18.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "oracledb": "^2.0.15",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

My babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ['react', 'es2015', "stage-2"],
  "plugins": ['react-html-attrs','transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties']
}
```

Any help is appreaciated.

Comment: is that the full error? if not, please include the _full_ error.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier or Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token. why babel is not able to load imports correctly?

Comment: Stil have not been able to figure this out would anyone have any suggestions for me to try?

Comment: As mentioned in https://github.com/babel/website/issues/1611, that error seems unrelated to any actual application functionality issues you might be having.